# Execute bash script from URL using python

Tags: python, bash, curl

Assume I have a file at http://mysite.com/myscript.sh that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello $1"
```

From the command line, I can execute my script (without downloading it) using the following command:

```
bash <(curl -s http://mysite.com/myscript.sh) World
```

Now, instead of executing the above command from the command line, I want to execute it from a python script. I tried doing the following:

```
import os
os.system('bash <(curl -s http://mysite.com/myscript.sh) World')
```

...but I get the following error:

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

How do I make this execute correctly in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, `os.system` runs its command through `/bin/sh`, which usually causes whichever shell it's linked to to drop to a compatibility mode that doesn't include the `<(...)` construction. You can get around it by either storing the result in a temporary file or using another level of shell. Ugly, but it works.

```
os.system('bash -c "bash <(curl -s http://mysite.com/myscript.sh) World"')
```

Comment: That almost works, except it doesn't seem to pick up the 'World' parameter.

Comment: It works if I leave out the double quotes: os.system('bash -c $(curl -s http://mysite.com/myscript.sh) World')

Comment: @Siou Apparently there is some odd interpretation of arguments going on. I've updated and tested this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a libcurl for python so you don't have to go the way around to command line behaviour. Here's the [function list](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/allfuncs.html) that should really do it - have never run remote scripts myself though. If you need installing the python binding, the instructions are [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/).

```
import curl
```